# How to stop rollback in MDB?

Tags: java, exception, transactions, rollback, message-driven-bean

I have a onMessage method where I'm reciving an ObjectMessage from the Queue and using that information to populate and persist a JPA entity object. But when something goes wrong while persisting the entity object it is re-executing the onMessage(). My guess is it is pushing the ObjectMessage back the queue and hence the onmessage is getting executed again. This way I'm entering an infinite loop. How can  stop onMessage() to get execute again or control the no of times it gets executed. Here is the code I have. 
Error is happening at saveAuditData(auditInfo).

```
public void onMessage(Message inMessage) {
   log.debug("Entering onMessage() Method.");
   AuditInfo auditInfo = null;
   try {
       ObjectMessage om = (ObjectMessage) inMessage;  
       auditInfo = (AuditInfo) om.getObject();
       log.debug("Message received : " + auditInfo.getApiUsed());
       log.debug("Calling saveAuditData().");
       saveAuditData(auditInfo);
       log.debug("Leaving onMessage() Method.");
   }
   catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
       log.debug("Error persisting Audit Info.",e);
       log.debug("Printing Audit Info:");
       log.debug(auditInfo.toString());
   }

}
private void saveAuditData(AuditInfo auditInfo) {
    log.debug("Entering saveAuditData() Method.");
    log.debug("Populating Audit Object.");
    IdmAudit idmAudit = new IdmAudit();
    idmAudit.setApiUsed("API");
    idmAudit.setAppClientIpAddress("localhost");
    idmAudit.setAuditActivity("activity1");
    idmAudit.setAuditData(auditInfo.getAuditData());
    idmAudit.setAuditGroup(AUDIT_GROUP);
    idmAudit.setAuditType("Type");
    idmAudit.setIdmAuditCreationDate(new Date());
    idmAudit.setLocationCd("Location");
    idmAudit.setPurgeDate(null);
    idmAudit.setSubscriberId(new BigDecimal(0));
    idmAudit.setSuccessInd("Y");
    idmAudit.setUserId(new BigDecimal(0));
    idmAudit.setAuditSource("Source");
    idmAudit.setVersionNumber(new BigDecimal(0));

    log.debug("Saving Audit.");
    entityManager.persist(idmAudit);
    entityManager.flush();
    log.debug("Leaving saveAuditData() Method.");
}
```

Answer (score 9):

When a container-managed transaction is started by the container to process a JMS message, any failure in JDBC connections or exception thrown in the thread will result into a rollback of the global XA transaction. So the message goes back to the queue and will be retry later according to the queue configuration: period between retries, maximum number of retry before moving the message to a dead-letter queue.

So you have the following options:

- Choose "Bean managed" transaction mode in your MDB deployment descriptor and use UserTransaction from lookup to `java:comp/UserTransaction` to call `begin`, `commit` or `rollback` manually, so care your exception handling.
- Keep "Container managed" transaction but query the redelivery count property on the JMS message to decide what to do next: either try again something that can fail or either skip this step and save your data in database. You can get redelivery info on your message from  `Message.getJMSRedelivered()` or `Message.getLongProperty("JMSXDeliveryCount")` if your JMS provider delivers it.
- Or else, move your `saveAuditData` method to a EJB StatelessBean with transaction support `RequiresNew` in deployment descriptor so that a new transaction is created and your data is saved whatever happens to your MDB transaction. This option can be combined with the previous one.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply mark the onMessage method with the TransactionType annotation:

```
@TransactionAttribute(value=TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void onMessage(Message message) {
     .....
}
```

Comment: Hi Acasolla. I get this message when tried what you tell:

Multiple markers at this line
 - implements javax.jms.MessageListener.onMessage
 - JSR 345: EJB 3.2, 8.37: The REQUIRES_NEW transaction attribute type value is not valid for a message-driven bean message listener method. Specify the REQUIRED or 
  NOT_SUPPORTED value.

I think this will not work.